# How to animate ApexCharts timeline chart continuously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

Currently, the timeline chart receives data as such:

```
y: [
    new Date(startTime.toDate()).getTime(),
    new Date(endTime.toDate()).getTime()
]
```

So it receives 2 point of datetime and it plots the timeline chart. This `startTime` and `endTime` is generated when I clicked on a `Start/Pause` button. So when I click on `Start`, the `startTime` will be generated while the `endTime` will be `null`. How can I simulate `endTime` as if it continues counting, hence the `endTime` will keep on adding 1 second for each second, animating the chart as if it is getting longer and longer until I press on the `Pause` button.

## Update

I'm currently using `setInterval` as such:

```js
const [animateTime, setAnimateTime] = useState(new Date())

useEffect(() => {
    let interval: any = null;
    let milliseconds = 1000;
    if (isInitialLoad) {
      setInitialLoad(false);
    } else {
      if (!pause) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          setAnimateTime(
            (animateTime) => new Date(animateTime.getTime() + milliseconds)
          );
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [pause]);
```

but weirdly, it doesn't start at `00:00:00` and the charts won't show up.

Comment: My initial idea is to use `setInterval` but I don't know how to achieve it because `setInterval` needs a specific amount of time to be inputted.